# Debian 9: synaptic package manager won't launch from command line

Tags: debian, command-line, synaptic

Every time I enter this line:

```
sudo pkexec synaptic
```

The synaptic package manager opens, but always followed by this error message:

```
E: Could not open file  - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

If I close the error box, synaptic will simultaneously close with it. How do I fix this bug and finally launch synaptic?

@Henrik, I just ran

```
 sudo apt update
```

This is the complete response that was generated in terminal:

```
Ign:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease [91.8 kB]
Hit:3 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch Release         
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 
Packages.diff/Index [27.8 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 
2018-12-24-0808.38.pdiff [622 B]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 
2018-12-24-0808.38.pdiff [622 B]
Fetched 120 kB in 1s (75.7 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/Release.gpg: The key(s) 
in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg are ignored as the file is not 
readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
W: http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-backports/InRelease: The 
key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg are ignored as the file is not 
readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
```

Comment: Maybe I should re-install debian? There doesn't seem to be anyway around this.

Comment: I had never heard of `pkexec` before, but a quick look at the man page suggets to me that it's rather redundant in your command. I've never cared for synaptic, so I don't know if the problem might be synaptic-specific or if your package database has been destroyed. My suggestion is that you try to run `sudo apt update` and show us the *complete* input+output, maybe that will tell us something that allows us to help you. Whether there's a way around it depends a lot on what has happened.

Comment: Google has lots of suggestions for this error. Which one(s) have you already tried?

Comment: @Henrik See my recent edit above for response, as it was too long for comment section.

Comment: @roaima There are fixes for it in the different versions of ubuntu and mint, but there's nothing for it in debian 9. The closest I could find was for debian squeeze/wheezy (https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=708294), but the info is outdated because there appears to be no synaptic.conf file in root.

Comment: Fundamentally all of Debian, Ubuntu, Mint are similar enough that those fixes _might_ work. (Or they might not.) Have you tried any of them yet?

Comment: @roaima Yes, that's true. I looked at this page here, which is for an older version of ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+bug/1243615. I deleted the settings Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache ""; and Dir::Cache::pkgcache ""; in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d. As a result, I'm now able to access synaptic, although reloading synaptic does produce another error message, but that's a topic for another question, unless I manage to solve it through another Google search.

Comment: Sounds like that would be a good answer. Write it up, mark it as the best answer, and get the points. (And help others with this issue.)